# Jenkins, kubernetes, getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes

Getting this weird error when building vuejs app -

```
[91merror An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/url/-/url-0.11.0.tgz: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.yarnpkg.com".
[0minfo If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/web/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

Tried to change ndots in the resolv conf - didn't work

I'm using node:latest image

When connection to this contained I'm able to resolve. Resolving on kube host works fine as well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to reach this address from the container ? `kubectl exec -ti pod-name curl -- --head https://registry.yarnpkg.com/url/-/url-0.11.0.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try increasing the network timeout?
It is possible the package yarn is installing could be too large or the network is too slow (This happened on my mac when i install yarn on docker)

Try either

```
yarn add YourPackageHere --network-timeout 100000
or
yarn install --network-timeout 1000000
```